# Error counting non-NA entries in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to see if the amount of information that I have about a case is correlated to the duration of the user.

Currently, I have a dataframe, df, and I attempted to do the following:

```
df["amount_known"] <-df[rowSums(!is.na(df)),]
```

This resulted in the following error:

> Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "amount_known", value = list(status = c(3L,  : 
>     replacement element 1 has 808047 rows, need 808247

What could cause this to happen (and of course, how do I fix it)?

Comment: I think you are simply looking for this `df["amount_known"] = rowSums(!is.na(df))`

Comment: @Vlo (You are correct) so what was I doing?

Comment: @soandos you are selecting some rows from your df and assign them to df. `df["amount_known"] <- df[1:nrow(df)+1,]` this will reproduce the error.

Comment: You are subsetting your df with some indices, which are the sum of not NA in each of the rows, then assigning this subsetted dataframe back into the original dataframe as a column (which is totally valid syntactically since R is pretty loose/flexible in terms of syntax, but doesn't make much sense logically for me). I'm guessing the error occurs because some rows returns a rowSums of 0, which means that that particular row indexing is missing. R goes all spazzy because the replacement total length is not an integer multiple of your column length (which is needed to insert a df into a column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the number of non-NA entries in a new column `amount_known` in `df` you can do it like this:

```
df$amount_known <-rowSums(!is.na(df))
```

Here's a small example of what is happening:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = 66:68)
df$y[1] <- NA
df$x[3] <- NA

df
#   x  y
#1  1 NA
#2  2 67
#3 NA 68

rowSums(!is.na(df))
#[1] 1 2 1
```

This results in a vector with the number of non-NAs in df.

Now, if you do

```
df[rowSums(!is.na(df)),]
```

This will select the rows in the vector `c(1,2,1)` from df:

```
#    x  y
#1   1 NA
#2   2 67
#1.1 1 NA
```

So for example, row 1 is shown twice.

And in your code, you were then assigning that output to a new column in `df`.

Comment: @soandos I added a small example to explain what is happening in your code